# find and findAll return an empty array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In an ember 1.13.3 app, I have this route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('skill');
  }
});
```

And this model :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  acquired_skills: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true, inverse: 'acquired_skills' } ),
  searched_skills: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true, inverse: 'searched_skills' } )
});
```

This is the result returned by the api :

```
{"skills":[{"id":1,"name":"Ember","description":"JS Framework","link":null}]}
```

The array is empty. I can check it with this `console.log(this.store.find('skill').get('length'));` and I have 0.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`store.find()` is an asynchronous operation. It returns a promise. To access the actual data you have to pass a callback to the promise. When the data is fetched from the backend, the promise resolves and executes the callback, passing the data into it:

```
var foo = this.store.find('skill');

console.log("typeof foo", typeof foo);

foo.then( function(result) {
  console.log("result", result);
});

console.log("end of script");
```

The above code would produce the following output:

> typeof foo, Promise
>   end of script
>   result, Object

## UPD 1

You're using a `JSONAPIAdapter`. The payload you've shown does not comply with the JSON API spec. You should update your backend to conform to the spec.

If you can't, use the `RESTAdapter` and `RESTSerializer` as a workaround:

**app/adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

**app/serializers/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  isNewSerializerAPI: false
});
```

More info here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html

Comment: I did `console.log("result", result.get('length'))` and I have 0. Anyway, `{{#each model as |skill|}}{{skill.name}}{{/each}}` Show nothing.

Comment: Well, then you have to share the payload you're receiving from the backend.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a JSbin or anything? I used your code to create a small app on my computer and I'm not having any problems. Are you getting any console errors or warnings? My `{{#each}}` is printing out the skill name as expected.

Comment: `store.find()` makes a request to the backend. Do you have a backend or a backend mock to serve some data?

Comment: Yes I have, this is the result of the backend : `{"skills":[{"id":1,"name":"Ember","description":"JS Framework","link":null}]}`. I can share the source code but I'm not sure than it can be useful.